# Connecting QlikView With Abinitio and UC4

Tags: qlikview, ab-initio

How can I most efficiently connect AbInitio with QLikView and UC4?
I am familiar with the QVX option. Is
What ist the interface between these two systems.
(Description in German would use me better, but in English is also )

Answer (score 1):

i'm not familiar with connecting with this systems. But if they have a proper api you can try code an qvsource (http://www.qvsource.com/) connector which will make the connection between the systems an qv.

Regards!
Stefan

Comment: As Stefan notes, QVSource might be an option - it has a General XML/JSON/SOAP Web Connector (http://wiki.qvsource.com/General-Web-Connector-For-QlikView.ashx) which allows you to construct HTTP requests and parse the response into a format which QlikView/Qlik Sense can read. You will find a number of examples showing it connecting to various types of APIs on the above doc page.